# Como passar um dict dentro de uma função, para ser usado em qualquer caso, se necessário?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dicionário

Boa tarde, estou com um grande problema de keyError, pois no meu programa que faz uso de Dict ira realizar diversos processos, e se algum momento ele não achar um item no qual ele procura, ira me gerar um keyError. Então fiz uma função simples que pudesse-me auxiliar Nesse Caso.Porem não vejo uma maneira de padronizar está função criada para utilizar em diversas dicts,apenas passando os valores chaves para fazer a tal mudança.
    Funcionamento: Ela atribui um item novo a um outro item que já contem valor.Após isso ele ira deletar o item antigo no qual quero substituir.

## A função foi utilizado para ajustar o seguinte dict de teste, x = {'Name':'Marcos','Age':21}

```
    def Test(dictionary):
        dictionary['Name1'] = dictionary['Name']
        del dictionary['Name']
        return dictionary

print(Test(x))
```

> {'Name1':'Marcos','Age':21}

## Eu gostaria que ficasse em um formato que possa ser utilizado para qualquer caso.

```
def Test(dictionary):
    newkey = oldkey
    del oldkey
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode (e deve) adicionar mais dois argumentos para função: `oldKey` e `newKey`. Assim, quando você chamar esta função, você pode modificar agora com dados dinâmicos.

```py
def ChangeDictKey(dictionary, oldKey, newKey):
    dictionary[newKey] = dictionary[oldKey]
    del dictionary[oldKey]
    return dictionary

dictionary = {'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 21}
dictionary = ChangeDictKey(dictionary, 'Age', 'Marriage Age')
print(dictionary)
```

Mas como dicionários são mutáveis, você pode deixar a função sem retorno. Apensar processando ele. Ou seja, assim:

```py
def ChangeDictKey(dictionary, oldKey, newKey):
    dictionary[newKey] = dictionary[oldKey]
    del dictionary[oldKey]

dictionary = {'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 21}
ChangeDictKey(dictionary, 'Age', 'Marriage Age')
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Valeu Breno, eu estava passando valores entre conchetes no momento de chamar a função para tal dict, Resolvido! Abrss

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @Breno foi muito boa, só vou complementar caso queira trocar mais de uma chave na mesma chamada da função `ChangeDictKey`:

```
def ChangeDictKey(dictionary, oldKeys, newKeys):
    for oldKey, newKey in zip(oldKeys, newKeys):
        dictionary[newKey] = dictionary[oldKey]
        del dictionary[oldKey]

dictionary = {'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 21}
ChangeDictKey(dictionary, ['Age', 'Name'], ['Marriage Age', 'Original Name'])

>>> print(dictionary)
{'Marriage Age': 21, 'Original Name': 'John Doe'}
```

Nessa abordagem, sempre deve-se passar os argumentos da chave dentro de listas ou tuplas (mesmo para trocar apenas uma chave).

Comment: O legal é que ainda há inúmeras maneiras se aplicar isso. Como usando o parâmetro `**kwargs*`, chamando a função com `ChangeDictKey(dictionary, Name='Original Name', Age='Marriage Age')` .